# PyPortfolioOpt returns same weight to each stock when number is stock is large

Tags: python, stock, portfolio

I was using the PyPortfolioOpt library to optimize the portfolio of around 500 stocks by 30 days of historical data. However, PyPortfolioOpt simply outputs equal weights (0.002) to each stock of the portfolio. After some testing, I realize that if I reduce the number of stocks (e.g. if I only have 50 stocks), the library works as it normally would, but it starts giving equal weights to every stock when the number of stocks is larger than somewhere around 90 stocks. Is it supposed to behave this way or did I do something wrong?

Here is my code

```
    # estimate expected returns and covariance matrix
    mu = mean_historical_return(prices, compounding=True)
    S = sample_cov(prices)

    # Mean-variance optimization
    ef = EfficientFrontier(mu, S)
    ef.add_objective(objective_functions.L2_reg, gamma=0.1) 
    # w = ef.min_volatility()
    w = ef.nonconvex_objective(
        objective_functions.sharpe_ratio,
        objective_args=(ef.expected_returns, ef.cov_matrix),
        weights_sum_to_one=True,
    )
```

Also, should the input of the library be 1+percentage change or raw percentage change? I tried both and it seems like it should be 1+percentage change, but even that doesn't work for a portfolio of 500 stocks. I also tried to increase the number of days of historical prices to 600 but it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem!